# spring + velocity how to handle URL between dev and production?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, velocity

`<c:url value="/vm/index" />` could translate relative url to absolute url in JSP page.
Is there any similar solution in velocity?
now my solution is:

```
public class ConstVar {
    pulic static String AAAAAAAAAAAAA = "http://localhost:8080/appName/index";
}

@RequestMapping("/index")
public String index(Model model)
{
    model.addAttribute("indexPageUrl", ConstVar.AAAAAAAAAAAAA);
    return "index";
}
```

in vm:

```
<a href="$indexPageUrl">Home</a>
```

it works! but I have to change ConstVar class & rebuild & republish if any URL changes.

Comment: You should ask a separate question for the jsp:include part

Comment: @BedwyrHumphreys I dont know why jsp:include?

Comment: I'm just saying that this question is about handling property differences between dev and production environments and that you should ask a separate question about the header and footer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the url from a property file, a database table or a JVM option - that way you will not need to recompile and the application can determine values from the environment it is deployed to.

Comment: good solution! but in each controller function the url list object should be added into ModelAndView, it's repetitive and boring

Comment: Putting it in the model gives you a request scoped attribute - maybe there's another scope you can use ...